# file and folder permissioins

Tags: permissions, files, samba, directory

I have an Ubuntu file server (samba) sharing a folder structure with a Windows 7 computer classroom. All users use the same user/pass to access the folders and have read/write permissions.

I would like to prevent users from moving or deleting folders, but keep the file permissions. In other words, I would like to protect my folder structure, but allow users to add/delete/rename/move files within that structure.
for example:
file server has the follwing folder structure:
/share/classes
classes folder has class1 class2  folders
and each class folder has user1 user2 folders
so the full path to the user folders would be: /share/classes/class1/user1
i would like for users to be able to add/delete/rename/move file in classes folder and below, but prevent them from add/delete/rename/move of folders.

How can I do that?
thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for ACLs. [Read this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissionsACLs) and then check out [this GNOME GUI ACL control](http://rofi.roger-ferrer.org/eiciel/)

Comment: thank you very much jan. eiciel did the trick for me: i gave only the lowest folders in the hirarchy rwx permissions. all higher folders got only rx. this way users cannot change the folder structure, only save/change/delete files in the user folders.